# Is there any method to Instant Print to PDF with Selenium in Google Chrome?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, powerbi

I have a task to automate exporting data from PowerBI RS.
I need to open specific link to PowerBI report. And then press buttons 'File', 'Print File To PDF', to get exact PDF file, that I can save on my disk and send by e-mail or Telegram.
The last part is the hardest for me.

I've got problem on the last stage, when I need to save file with specific name on specific directory.
There's two possible problems:

1. The program stops on 'Print' window, where I need to select exact printer (Print To PDF), if i place google chrome option:
   chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-print-preview')
2. The program stops on 'Save print result' window, when i need to insert path to my directory and filename.

I've tried:

1.

```
downloadPath = r'mypath\\downloadPdf\\'
   appState = {
   "recentDestinations": \[
   {
   "id": "Save as PDF",
   "origin": "local"
   }
   \],
   "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
   "version": 2
   }

profile = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState':json.dumps(appState)}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile)
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
pdfPath = r'mypath\\protected.pdf'
driver.get(pdfPath)
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

2. 

```
prefs = {
    "printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState": json.dumps(settings),
    "savefile.default_directory": "/Users/creative/python-apps",
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "download.safebrowsing.enabled": True
```

3. 

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Create ChromeOptions object
chrome_options = Options()
# Set the saving destination directory for the PDF
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-print-preview')
chrome_options.add_argument('--print-to-pdf="C:/path/to/save/folder/output.pdf"')

# Create a new Chrome driver with the specified options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

4. PyAutoGUI
   To select address bar by pressing 'Tab' and inserting filepath.
   And then select filename bar and insert filename there.
   It's the best choice now, but it's not stable. It's not working on blocked PC (Win+L).
   PyAutoGUI can have some problems with symbols in file path.

Now I think about libs:

1. subprocess
2. pywinauto

But I'm not sure, that it would work.

My main questions is:

1. Can I skip filepath and filname selection in GoogleChrome to save document through PrintToPDF to specific folder?
2. If i can't, is there any libs, that can interact with 'Save print result' window in GoogleChrome that can select exact bars in one action (select filepath bar, insert path, select filename bar and insert filename)?
3. If there's no specific libs, can i set PyAutoGUI to work on locked PC (Win+L)?